# Is there a way to modify the coordinates of a mouse click event?

Tags: html, typescript, dom-events

I'm working on a clicking / guessing game in the browser, and tackling an issue where I need to show some small popover, on a different, calculated position of the app page.
I am looking into a way to modify the coordinates of the given 'click' event in the popover function, but don't see to be able to figure it out.

Here's a basic example of the 'popover' function:

```
  private presentPopover(ev: Event, data: any) {

    let resultPopover = this.popoverCtrl.create(
      ResultPopover,
      {data: entry},
      {cssClass: 'result-popover'}
    );

    console.log(ev);

    /*
     here comes the code to manipulate the event coordinates
     */     

    // Show the popover on a calculated position, relative to the event
    resultPopover.present(
        {ev: ev, animation: true}
    );

    resultPopover.onDidDismiss(() => {
        // Do something after the popover is removed.
    });
  }
```

Comment: is `presentPopover` your click event?

Comment: ```presentPopover``` is the function that takes in the click event ```ev```. The function is called by clicking on an other DOM element.

Comment: In what way are you not able to modify the event coordinates? Have you checked the coordinates before and after modification, and they have not changed, or is the popover appearing at the wrong position, despite the coordinates successfully changing on the event object?

Comment: @Wingnod The problem is that I can not figure out how to modify the coordinates of the event. I can read them, but not change them.